# Problemas para pegar valor do ResultSet

Tags: java, sql

Estou tentando pegar os valores de um select no derby mas eles só retorna corretamente um campo do ResulteSet.
Segue o código da classe de acesso ao DB:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.management.RuntimeErrorException;

public class Conexao {
    private Connection con;
    private String URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ATM";

    public Conexao() {
        // Obter conexao
        try {

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // mostra erro
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return con;
    }

    public Conta autenticacao(int agencia, int conta, String senha)
            throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = getConnection().createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT AGENCIA, CONTA, SENHA, SALDO FROM contas WHERE AGENCIA=%d AND CONTA=%d AND SENHA='%s'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(String.format(sql, agencia, conta, senha));

        if (rs.next()) {
            // conta autenticada
            Conta conta1 = new Conta(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2),rs.getString(3), rs.getDouble(4));
            return conta1;
        } else {

            throw new RuntimeException("Erro de autenticacao");
        }
    }
}
```

O Objeto Conta:

```
public class Conta {

    private int Agencia;
    private int Conta;
    private String Senha;
    private double Saldo;
    private boolean Tipo;

    public Conta() {};


    public Conta(int agencia, int conta, String senha, double saldo) {
        setAgencia(agencia);
        setConta(conta);
        setSenha(senha);
        setSaldo(saldo);
    }

    private void setAgencia(int agencia) {
        if (agencia > 999 && agencia <= 0) {
            Agencia = agencia;
        } else {
            System.out.println("numero invalido");
        }
    }

    private void setConta(int conta) {

        if (conta < 0 && conta > 99999) {
            Conta = conta;
        }
    }

    public void setSaldo(double saldo) {

        Saldo = saldo;
    }

    private String getSenha() {
        return Senha;
    }

    private void setSenha(String senha) {
        Senha = senha;
    }

    public int getAgencia() {
        return Agencia;
    }

    public int getConta() {
        return Conta;
    }

    public double getSaldo() {
        return Saldo;
    }

}
```

Classe que faz o teste de conexão:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TesteO {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            // Ler dados
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Agencia");
            int agencia = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Numero");
            int numero = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Senha");
            String senha = sc.next();

            Conexao atm = new Conexao();
            Conta conta = atm.autenticacao(agencia, numero, senha);

             //exibe saldo atual

            System.out.println("Agencia = " + conta.getAgencia());
            System.out.println("Conta = " + conta.getConta());
            System.out.println("Saldo = " + conta.getSaldo());
            //System.out.println("Valor para deposito: ");
            //double valor = sc.nextDouble();
            //if (valor > 0) {
            //  atm.atualizaSaldo(saldo + valor);
            //}
            //saldo = atm.saldo();
            //System.out.println("Novo Saldo = " + saldo);

        }
    }
}
```

Estrutura do DB(DERBY):

```
connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ATM;create=true';
create table contas (
 agencia int not null,
 conta int not null,
 senha char(6) not null,
 saldo double not null,
 primary key (agencia,conta)
 );
insert into contas values(1,123,'123',1000);

insert into contas values(1,321,'321',1100);

 describe contas;
```

Ao executar a função o objeto conta recebe apenas o saldo os outros campos ficam com valor 0 e aparece uma mensagem "Numero Invalido" que acredito ser um exception do SQL.

Comment: Uma pergunta? pra que usar String.format para substituir campos no select, se você já tem o [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que a lógica dos métodos setters está errada e por isso o valor não é atribuído. Não porque não retorna os dados do banco.

Vamos supor que retorne o número 1 da conta, será executado este método setter, não tem else para tratar, justamente porque a conta não atende a condição. 1 não é menor que zero e maior que 99999.

```
private void setConta(int conta) {
     if (conta < 0 && conta > 99999) {
          Conta = conta;
     }
}
```

Exemplo: entra 1, como conta, 1 não está entre o intervalo do IF, o que o programa faz? Nada, não atribui o valor ao atributo conta. Tire o if e simplesmente faça this.Conta = conta;